# Is there a SET option equivalent to "Discard results after execution"?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

In MS SQL, there are [SET options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-statements-transact-sql) to control the connection properties, e.g. `SET NOCOUNT ON/OFF`, `SET XACT_ABORT ON/OFF`, etc. that are mirrored in the connection properties and options dialogs in Management Studio.

**Is there a similar SET OPTION** (or some other command) **to mirror the connection property "Discard results after execution"?** Just to be clear, I'm looking for a script to set this option rather than having to use the SSMS user interface.

[image: SSMS query options]

The connection properties are most easily accessed by right clicking in the query text editor window, then Query Options. But they can also be accessed from the Tools menu > Options, although they are not grouped in the same ways. E.g. Tools > Options > Query Results > SQL Server > Results to Grid (or Text) (here is the option "Discard results after execution"), as well as Tools > Options > Query Execution > SQL Server > Advanced (here are `SET NOCOUNT`, `SET XACT_ABORT` etc.)

Comment: That setting has nothing to do with the SQL being run and is purely an SSMS setting related to how SSMS does (or doesn't) display the results. `SET NOCOUNT ON` and other options like that change how the query runs, it has nothing to do with the presentation layer. You can't have a statement like `SET DISCARD_RESULTS ON;` as even if it *were* valid, as soon as you ran the statement outside of SSMS it wouldn't work. SSMS options aren't set in T-SQL, they are set in SSMS and SSMS only.

Comment: The closest thing to this if it were to be supported would be to put SSMS in `sqlcmd` mode and issue an `:out nul` -- unfortunately this is explicitly prohibited by SSMS, which refuses to accept device names. (Curiously enough `:out stdout` does work, and is like using the "results to text" option.)

Comment: Have you tried `SET ROWCOUNT 1`? This is not exactly what you want, but I guess it is *almost* what you want. :)

Comment: @МаксимЗолотенко: that's a very poor idea if the script contains anything but `SELECT` statements. `ROWCOUNT` specifies a limit to the number of rows *affected*, regardless of whether they are part of the result set, so all inserts, updates and deletes will then affect at most one row as well.

Answer (score -3):

Similar to MSSQL, SQL Server also has SET Options. Few of them are:

1. SET NOCOUNT (Under maintenance mode)
2. SET ARITHABORT
3. SET XACT_ABORT

Detailed information of more such options can be found on:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-statements-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!! This question is about a SET OPTION for "Discard results after execution". Does your answer, or the link you provided in your answer, mention how to do that?